# dbconcurrency exception

Tags: c#, asp.net

In a page i insert a record in a Missioni table:

```
MissioniDataSet.MissioniRow newMissioniRow;
newMissioniRow.AccontoAutorizzato = 0;
...
missioniDataSet._Missioni.Rows.Add(newMissioniRow);
missioniTableAdapter.Update(missioniDataSet._Missioni);
```

If there are some condition, i update also some attributes of this table in the same page.

When i  update the record with this:

```
missioniTableAdapter.Update(missioniDataSet._Missioni);
```

i receive this error.

```
Concurrency violation: the UpdateCommand affected 0 of the expected 1 records.
```

this happens only when before the insert of the record the table was empty.
When there are some records there isn't any problem.

Why?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the data adapter thinks the row maps to an existing row, because the adapter is attempting to update the row (which fails because the row doesn't exist).

Are you calling `missioniDataSet._Missioni.NewRow()` to create the data row?